# Create Vector list in Animation node

Tags: append, loop, vector

I need help to make a Vector List in Animation node.

What I tried you can [have it in the link](https://github.com/kebab03/create_list_vector) https://blend-exchange.com/b/w7OPLjo6 this work if I use Append list (done for 2d vector ) with vector list inside the loop  and same thing doesn't work when I pass the vector list in to the loop a take vector to append from the list through *get element* node (you can see scheme in  the file finished with 3.blnd in github ).

What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hi Kebab, i really love animation nodes and i would help you - if you would be more thankful, but you aren't. And you aren't willing to try things out yourself and additionally although Duarte wrote several times you shouldn't write in  all caps you are still writing in all caps. You expect people who write you an answer that you even get a blend file presented all on a silver tablet so that you have nothing to do and nothing to try out. But that's not the way how you learn to deal with Blender.

Comment: And you ask a lot of questions - but you only hit "accept answer" one single (!) time - that's why you aren't thankful in my eyes. And by the way: if you cannot read an image, you can click on it, it will be zoomed.

Comment: and blend files should be provided here: https://blend-exchange.com/ and not on github, because your question gets a bit worthless if you decide to delete your blend file on github. thx.

Comment: Hello mrs Chris.Reguarding your alligation of not being kind I think I add "Thanks" @ the end of my question ,Any way From today I will give Accept  every time some one give some answer .Further more  I didn't know that file should be added in blender site & not in Github .Finally as you noticed I eidted my writing in small letters ,My only intention of using Caps was underling  the  title of the question.Anyway Please help with your knowledge, Because I tried a lot befor asking question here ,it's not true that I don't do anything my self.

Comment: Dear Chris   can you please have a look to other commets  done by me where  I told you that I didn't understand you answer, I you really Have some time please,give me you precious Help.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wish someOne really help me out.

Comment: First: you still can accept old anders. No one stops you to do that. Second: why don’t you change your question and upload your file as I wrote in the comment? Instead of writing long comments, just do it. Instead complaining.

Comment: Mrs Chris ,Now can you help me please?

Comment: uhm....this is what i see when i open your downloaded file: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrpfE.png ....this is a bit different from what you showed in the question. Could you please make it the same? Thx. And honestly: i would like to have the file from the picture - i don't want you to exchange the picture, thx.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/LBkkS1Js   here you get file from which  I took the screen shoot used for question .And the photo you saw was from the last file that  I made . So if you under stand What I asked ,may be you will find the error in this file and How to make a model that is optimised. Thank you for answering me .

Comment: to be honest, i don't understand what's your problem is. Is it the result of vector list after invoking your "blue" myLoop? would be great if you could tell me the result you are getting and the result you would expect. To my understanding the result of the vector list is correct. You are adding 3,2,6 inside the loop and you are reassigning this, so you get 3,2,6 -> 6,4,12 -> 9,6,18 which is correct. So i seem to misunderstand you...

Comment: I want to make first 20 sec of the video @https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r18Gi8lSkfM&t=9s   for that I made this model @ https://blend-exchange.com/b/x1xz89z3   .My problem is that the Icosfere should be only @ the tip of the rod ,which is not happening so I thought that if I can create the vector list of the tip with that I can put the Icoshere  using Obj Instancer in those position. So to make It work ,Kindly  help me.Hope you are kind to me.

Comment: Thank you, this information was really helpful. Unfortunately I am back on my computer in the evening, so hopefully someone helps helps you today or I will try tomorrow latest.

Comment: Will be waiting.Thanks for being kind .

Comment: question: does it have to be animation nodes or is GN ok too?

Comment: No problem if you make it in GN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create your base object (cylinder with icosphere as one object). Important is here that the origin point of the object is at the center (0,0) as here in my picture:

[image]

Then create a plane, add a geometry nodes modifier with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Explanation:

If you want to "debug" or understand a geometry nodes setup, it is always a good idea to mute nodes to see the difference or what's happening.

So here i muted these nodes:

[image]

and as you can see the objects will be just stacked on each other on the z axis by the unmuted nodes.

These four nodes here:

[image]

are responsible for the z-rotation of the object. Depending on the index they will be just multiplied with a certain value. Of course you can change this value if you want to have different angles. But keep in mind that you have to change other frame dependent values too so that the animation works correct again.

[image]

These four nodes make the instances visible after a certain time. So they are responsible for one part of the animation.

The last nodes here:

[image]

...are responsible for the animation of the "one" cylinder which is moving all around. It is moved on the z axis and rotated on the z axis as well. To be honest, i did not calculate the multiply-values but i just eye-balled it so that the animation looks ok. You can use calculated values if you want to - i was too lazy for that.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much , The image is not very clear.Can you upload the file please.

Comment: the first node setup (2nd image) is total clear. Just click on it and it will be zoomed, but i uploaded the blend file anyway.

Comment: Mrs Chris ,thank you very much , for helping me .what if the lenth of the rod should very because the radius of the path is verying because I add two sine wave of different frequecy?

Comment: this is a new question and not part of this question so please open a new question for this so that everybody can find the question and the answer. Answers and questions in comments won't be found be the SE search engine.